# How to request focus on spinner after pressing the enter key on a different spinner

Tags: java, javafx, focus, spinner

So I have 2 `Spinner`s, `windVelSpinner` and `launchTubeSpinner`. They have the following on Key Pressed Actions (I am using scene builder): `windSpinAction` and `launchSpinAction` is what I called them. Here is the `windSpinAction` method:

```
@FXML
void windSpinAction(KeyEvent ke) {
    if (ke.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER)) {
        launchTubeSpinner.requestFocus();
    } // end if statement
```

When I run the program and hit <kbd>enter</kbd> while the focus is on `windVelSpinner` nothing happens. But if I hit <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> it moves the focus to `launchSpinAction`. Why is this the case and how can I get around that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with pressing <kbd>shift</kbd> or not. Since you use the `onKeyPressed` events, the event triggers on the first `Spinner` which makes the second `Spinner` receiving focus while the key is still pressed, so the second `Spinner` receives the event too and the first `Spinner` gets the focus again which receives the event again changing the focus to the second `Spinner` again and so on...

The result is the focus ending more or less random at one of the `Spinner`s.

Use the [`onKeyReleased`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#onKeyReleasedProperty) event that is triggered only once per key press instead.

---

If you have editable `Spinner`s and want to change the focus after a user input, use the [`onAction`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextField.html#onActionProperty) event of the [`editor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Spinner.html#editorProperty) instead of the key event on the `Spinner`.

```
windVelSpinner.getEditor().setOnAction(e -> {
    launchTubeSpinner.requestFocus();
});
```

(in the `initialize` method)